# Perceptual salience of two consecutive syllables

Tags: phonology, phonetics, syllables, formants

Imagine the f0 of two subsequent syllables.

- The first rises from 200Hz to 300Hz and the second from 300Hz to 400Hz
- In other words,  rises are both 100 Hz.

Why is it the case that the first has more perceptual salience?

Comment: Do you have experimental evidence to demonstrate that? Also, have you controlled for order -- 200-300 + 300-400 vs. 300-400 + 200-300? What exact question did you ask of subjects that you call "salience"? It's very popular to make up hypothetical experimental results and wonder what causes them: I just want to direct your attention to the factual presumption. "Plausible" is not the same as "proven".

Comment: Yes, we need much more information here.  When you say "subsequent", do you mean they are both in a single utterance?  Are there other syllables around them?  Are they real words or just nonsense syllables?  How long are the syllables?  How loud are the syllables?

Answer (score 3):

We hear proportions of frequencies, not absolute differences. In the first case, the proportion 300Hz/200Hz = 1.5; in the second case the proportion 400Hz/300Hz = 1.33. In musical terms, the first proportion is a perfect fifth or quint and the second proportion is a perfect fourth or quart.